# token (or something else) needed to use wikipedia api using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, api, wikipedia

I need a java code to use wikipedia api. I would like to get the tags of a specific value on wikipedia (the tags that appear at the end of the page). I know that the api call I need is

```
"http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&titles=Albert%20Einstein&prop=categories" 
(for the example of Albert Einstein)
```

But I find it difficult to understand from the MediaWiki API documentation page if I need a token and hash, or to log in or not. I know that sometimes it is not necessary to log in.

Right now my code is:

```
JSONArray wikiResult=null;
String url1= "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&titles=Albert%20Einstein&prop=categories";
wikiResult=ApiCall(url1);
```

where ApiCall is a function that sends the call, and it works fine, I have checked it.
the JSONArray returned is empty.

Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to log in or get token for `prop=categories`.

The actual error is probably explained in the response. It's possible that you're getting an empty result, because the response is not JSON (that happens with some errors).

If I were to guess, I think you're not setting [the `User-Agent` header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) in your request, which [is required by Wikimedia wikis](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User-Agent_policy).

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how exactly I set the User-Agent? Do I need to create an account on Wikipedia? 
The only example I've found about how to set the User-Agent is the following one:
"ini_set('user_agent', 'MyCoolTool/1.1 (http://example.com/MyCoolTool/; MyCoolTool@example.com) BasedOnSuperLib/1.4');" 

Can you tell me what are the different fields of the User-Agent in the example above?
Thanks again!

Comment: @user2494680 I don't Java and you didn't tell us how exactly are you making the request, so I can't help you with that. But you certainly don't need an account.

Comment: Ok. The ini_set(string $varname, string $newvalue ) function is a php function that sets the value of a configuration option. Do you know what function can I use in Java to do the same?